# inputAccessoryView is readonly now?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview, inputaccessoryview

I have an Objective-C project, where I would like to add an inputAccessoryView to a subclass of UITextView. The old way was

`self.myTextView.inputAccessoryView = myView;`

(where myView was a UIView)

Now XCode (9.2) says "Assignment is readonly property"

When I try to use a setter, like this:

```
[self.myTextView setInputAccessoryView: myView];
```

XCode says "No visible @interface for 'customTextView' declares the selector 'setInputAccessoryView:'"

Anybody knows why is this? And how to actually set an inputAccessoryView?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it is not read-only as far as I know.. are you sure you are not doing anything in your customTextView declaration/implementation that messes it up?

Comment: `@property(readwrite, strong) UIView *inputAccessoryView;` from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618596-inputaccessoryview?language=objc

Comment: last time I checked (=0.3 secs ago) [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618596-inputaccessoryview?language=objc) was still read-write property.

Comment: show code of `customTextView`

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, but in the meantime it became clear to me, that I was actually trying to set the inputAccessoryView on the wrong object (which itself was not a subclass of UITextView). That object had a hidden textView, and on that one, it worked. (it is a huge project, and I joined the team just recently). Anyway I appreciate , that you guys took time for helping!

Answer (score -1):

From UIKit

```
@property (nullable, readwrite, strong) UIView *inputAccessoryView; //its not read only, its read-write. So you can set it.
```

So you can set it like below...

```
UIView *customView = [UIView new];
UITextField *txt = [UITextField new];
[txt setInputAccessoryView:customView];
```

I've used XCode 9.2 with iOS 11

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking *why* it doesn't work for his case.